# How can I reset the default project hosting with firebase?

Tags: firebase, terminal, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have been using firebase to test apps. I set a certain project as the default. Now I would like to deploy a different project but do not understand how to remove the previous project as a default. (I have almost no experience using the terminal).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the default project that the Firebase CLI uses in a directory by running:

```
firebase use --add
```

Then in the list of projects, select your project. And then finally for the alias name enter `default` (or whatever you entered before).

For a full list of the commands, have a look at the [reference documentation of the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#managing_project_aliases).